# How I can remove the estructure of Realm DataBase?

Tags: java, android, realm

```
public void removeAllData() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
    try {
        realm.close();
        new SessionManager(this).setLogin(false);
    } catch (IllegalStateException realmISE) {
        realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This method remove all data of the Realm Database, but it keep the estructure.

Thereafter, I have implemented this other method to get it, but when the app run notify a exception.

```
public void deleteDatabase(){
    try {
        realm.close();
        Realm.deleteRealm(realm.getConfiguration());
        //Realm file has been deleted.
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //No Realm file to remove.
    }
}



java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.controllers.activitys.LoginActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided
```

I don't need perform any migration because then I'll create other database from scratch.

Is there an alternative to remove the database completely, not only the data??

Comment: `RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).deleteIfMigrationNeeded().build();`?